# Metronome SwiftUI, Change timer interval whenever the @State var is changed

Tags: timer, swiftui, observableobject

I'm building the a metronome with swiftUI

I have a @State var that connect to a slider.

```
@State private var period: Double
Slider(value: period, in: 0.25...5, step: 0.25)
```

Right now I can only reset the time interval if I restart the metronome.

```
Button(action: { startStop = !startStop
    self.timer = Timer.publish(every: self.period, on: .main, in:.default).autoconnect()
            } ){
                Text("START/STOP")
            }
```

However, I want to trigger the "self.timer = Timer.publish(...." whenever the slider is moved. Is there a way to trigger an ObservableObject @Published var whenever a @State var is changed? So that I can use ".onReceive()" function to trigger "self.timer = Timer.publish(...."

Thank you

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but I just want to make sure that you know that if this is any more than an experiment, `Timer` or `DispatchQueue` are nowhere near reliable enough to actually make a metronome with precise timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to perform code when a `@State` value changes is to add an `onChange` modifier to a child view of the view where you defined your `@State`, e.g.:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var period: Double = 0.5

    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: period, in: 0.25...5, step: 0.25)
          .onChange(of: period) { newValue in
            // perform your code here
          }
    }
}
```

See also [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/onchange(of:perform:)) and an example on [Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-run-some-code-when-state-changes-using-onchange).

Comment: Hi Scott My Slider is in a subview of ContentView, it is the only way that pass the "timer" to the subview? Thank you

Comment: onChange needs OSX Big Sur, I use "onEditingChanged" instead